# Expressing a doubt between multiple items in an enumeration

Tags: grammar

Consider the sentence: "I am hesitating between A, B and C". What would go between A,B,C―迷っています?

Asking someone to make a choice seems more straightforward (I would say "A,B,C（の中）から選んでください".)

I could also find examples for choosing between two things (A,Bのどちらかを選ぶことを迷っています). However, how can it be modified to work with larger lists (considering that どちらか is more used for two options)?

Comment: I'm not aware of any limitation to "only 2" for どちら.  I think it operates much like "which" in English.  So AとBとCのどちらかを選ぶことを迷っています might work.

Comment: EDICT stresses that it is used (mostly) for two options. I checked a Japanese definition and it doesn't seem to be mentioned though, so maybe I was misled.

Comment: I've been corrected by my Japanese friends and teachers a number of times about this. It's usually better to use どれ when there are more than two options.

Comment: The shortest way I can think of would be A、B、Cの中で迷っています。

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  Maybe it is more a matter of conventional usage than a hard rule.  Either way I stand corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use どれ if you have more than two options.

For example, A、B、Cのどれを選ぶか迷っています.

If you have two options, you can use どちら as you said.